# jQuery UI doesn't work

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I wrote this code for another project and I'm trying to re-use it in my new one, but id doesn't work, while it still works on my other project. The code it's the same, so I can't really figure out why it shouldn't work.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.menu-responsive').on( "click", function() {
                $('.item_contains_responsive').toggle();
            });

            $("#porco").dialog({
                autoOpen:false
            });

            $("#data").datepicker({
                onSelect: function(d,i){
                    if(d !== i.lastVal){
                        $(this).change();
                    }
                    $("#startH").show();
                    $("#endH").show();
                    $("#submit").show();
                } 
            });
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                $.post("ricerca_data.php",{data: data.value, ora_inizio: startH.value, ora_fine: endH.value}, function(risultato) {
                        if(risultato == 1)
                            //alert("La palestra non è disponibile negli orari richiesti. Prova con orari diversi.");
                        else {
                            //LIBERA
                            $("#nameP").show();
                            $("#surname").show();
                            $("#telN").show();
                            $("#prenota").show();
                        }
                });
            });

            $("#prenota").click(function() {
                //alert(nameP.value);
                $.post("inserisci_prenotazione.php", {data: data.value, ora_inizio: startH.value, ora_fine: endH.value, nome: nameP.value, cognome: surname.value, telefono: telN.value}, function(result) {
                        //alert(result);
                });
            });


        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var width = $(window).width();
            if($('.item_contains_responsive').css('display') == 'block' && width > 673){
                $('.item_contains_responsive').hide();
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id='porco' name='porco'>
    <input type='text' id='data' name='data'>
    <input type='time' id='startH' name='startH' class='nascosta'>
    <input type='time' id='endH' name='endH' class='nascosta'>
    <input type='button' id='submit' name='submit' value='Controlla disponibilit&agrave;' class='nascosta'>
    <input type='text' id='nameP' name='nameP' placeholder='Nome' class='nascosta'>
    <input type='text' id='surname' name='surname' placeholder='Cognome' class='nascosta'>
    <input type='text' id='telN' name='telN' placeholder='Numero di telefono' class='nascosta'>
    <input type='button' id='prenota' name='prenota' value='Prenota' class='nascosta'>      
</div>
```

Instead of showing me the dialog with all the components inside it acts as normal and puts the div in the page. Also the datepicker doesn't work and it's showed as a textbox.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: Ops, forgot to explain that. Edited the question, sorry.

Comment: What error messages, if any, do you see on the console?   Are you sure you have included the jQuery library in the page?

Comment: @DanielBeck I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. And yes, I have the jQuery lib in the page.

Comment: You have a typo in your `$('#submit').click()`: missing a } before the 'else'.  Please check the console log for obvious error messages -- the line number in the message would have shown you exactly where the problem was.

Comment: @DanielBeck I don't think I'm missing brackets, the only error I get is the one I posted before. If I click on it takes me at:  $("#porco").dialog({, but as you can see from the code, the div is declared and shouldn't have problems

Comment: Ah, you are right -- I was thrown off by the mixed use of bracketless and bracketed clauses in the same if/else.  Apologies.  

`.dialog()` is a jquery UI function, not raw jquery; are you including the UI library?

Comment: @DanielBeck yes I am. Infact on the other page, where I took the code from and which is in the same folder, it works as it should. It's this page that doesn't act properly.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, then, sorry.  If I copy your code here it throws an error related to the missing {} in the if/else (I guess something about how the SO snippet editor parses the code gets confused by that as much as I did); if I fix that it throws an error about `dialog()` not being a function; if I add the jqueryUI library it appears to work fine.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks anyways!